# display a text from a list

Tags: list, text

I'm trying  to display several lines into a Text area from a string list. But it's only displaying the last one of the list, and i would like to display them all. Thanks for your help !

```
using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;


    public class contenuTexte : MonoBehaviour {
    public List <string> montexte;
    public GameObject zoneAffichage;



        // Update is called once per frame
        void Start ()
        {



            foreach ( string lines in montexte)
                zoneAffichage.GetComponent<Text>().text = "\n"+lines;

            }



        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are resetting the string on every loop to the last string. At the end of the loop you are going to only have the last string in the text.

First let's join all the strings together as one (using .ToArray() because of .NET 3.5), and then set them all at once:

```
var completeText = String.Join("\n", montexte.ToArray());

zoneAffichage.GetComponent<Text>().text = completeText;
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! But I'm getting compiler errors : "The best overloaded method match for `string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments" and Argument `#2' cannot convert `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' expression to type `string[]'

Comment: @tieum67 ah my bad I assumed your .NET version to be > 4 but you must be on .NET 3.5 or so. I will correct my answer for that version of .NET